# Kendo MVC treeview Passing selected node to grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, treeview, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

I'm new to Kendo, I just trying to pass the selected node of treeview to the grid, this is my code:

```
    <div>    
    @(
    Html.Kendo().TreeView()
        .Name("treeview")            
        .BindTo((IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel>)ViewBag.TreeData)
        .Events(events => events
            .Select("onSelect")).ExpandAll(true)
    )    
    </div>

 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<DocunetViewer.Models.MyModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ID);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Home").Data("getParameter")))
```

and this is the script:

```
    <script>
function onSelect(e) {        
    BindGrid();
}

function BindGrid() {
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
}

function getParameter() {
    var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
    var selectedNode = treeview.select();

    var id = -1;        
    if (selectedNode.length != 0) {
        var item = treeview.dataItem(selectedNode);
        id = item.id;                   
    }

    return {
        myId: id            
    };
}
```

my problem is that I always get the previous selected node not the current selected node, so what is the problem? and how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your onSelect method, you can get at the node with some JavaScript like this.

```
var node = ($(e.node));
```

and here I'm getting the id attribute of the node (your node may have different things on it).

```
var id = ($(e.node).data("id"));
```

Comment: thanks richardb, but how to pass this value to grid?

Comment: Do you mean pass it to the grids datasource call?  The GetData method should received the value as long as the getParameter javascript function gets the right node.  The BindGrid method fires the grids datasource refresh and that in turn gets the parameters.  You should the there.  What's missing?